# Reimplementing C# Inheritance with generics in F# using functional techniques

Tags: c#, generics, f#, functional-programming, polymorphism

My abstract goals are:

1) Create a CRUD API That is a wrapper of 3rd party library with CRUD interface(could be from service object and/or entity object)

2) Each CRUD method should limit the types fed to it based on predefined types definitions (one type can be fed to multiple methods)

3) When User chose a specific type of a method he should be forced to insert the right types of other parameters(like a key) based on the chosen type, And those should be validated in compile time(passing key as object type require runtime evaluation for the "real" type of the object).

4) The method's types is a 3rd party interfaces that are not in my control and I cannot alter them.

5) The API should be straightforward for the user with the less amount of boilerplate code for him.

One way that I found to solve this problem in C# is:

```
public interface Update<T,TKey> {}
public interface Add<T> {}
public interface Delete<T,TKey> {}
public interface Get<T,TKey> {}

public class Invoice:Get<string>, Add<ThirdPartyInvoice>, Update<ThirdPartyInvoice,string> {}
//More types can come here...

public static class CRUDAPI
{
  public static T Get<T,TKey>(Get<T,TKey> type, TKey key)
  {
    //will get a T from a service object based on TKey
  }
  public static Unit Add<T>(Add<T> type, Func<T,T> select)
  {
    //will get a new instance of T and will feed it to the select function.
    //and then will feed the result to the 3rd party add method
  } 
  public static Unit Update<T,TKey>(Update<T,TKey> type,TKey key, Func<T,T> select)
  {
    //will load an instance of T and will feed it to the select function.
    //and then will feed the result to the 3rd party update method
  } 
  public static Unit Delete<T,TKey>(Delete<T,TKey> type,TKey key)
  {
    //will load an instance of T and then will use 3rd party delete method
  } 
}
```

User can then use it like:

```
Add(new Invoice(), inv=> { inv.field1 = "123"; ... return inv;})
```

What could be a good way to solve this problem in a functional style(in F# for example)?

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent generic constraints?

Comment: With only generic constraints you won't get the "type mapping" that you are getting this way for example: When I Chose Invoice lets say in the Get method, TKey automatically will be asigned to string, And T to the specific object. In other words, choosing one parameter force the types of others

Comment: It can be solved easily, though will require you a lot of generic parameters to be passed in and out. F# would do exactly the same, however silently: so programmer merely would notice that. Generics are too explicit in C#, hence - quite limited. The only reasonable trade-off I see is to get "one level down" and deal with precise generic commands. You're kinda did the same, but in a oversimplified way. The other option - is to write proper library in F# and wrap it with C#-like interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

In functional programming you would solve that problem with **generic** [algebraic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). You'll normally would decide to deal with a "command" primitive like:

```
data Command a b c = Command(a -> Either b c)
```

It is up to you to find a right balance between command's specificity, number of generic parameters, and general (in-out) interface: though [Either](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) is a classical choice, also available in F#; the other commonly used type is [Maybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html), also provided by F#.

Then you can define:

```
data CRUD a b c d e f = CRUD{ create :: Command a b c, read :: Command d e f, ... }
```

Once again, find the right balance.

Then you figure out, that there are lots and lots of commands. Really. Some of them go directly to the database, other responsible for DTO -> Model mappings, other deal with validation. You'd like to compose them in a LEGO-fashion: `Command a b c -> Command b e d -> Command a e d`, which can be solved by extending your `Command` algebraic type: `... | CompositeCommand(a -> Either b c, b -> Either e d)`, which internally will rely on the `Either`'s monadic binding to chain both functions.

Comment: using your model: lets say command a b c should reflect a get/read command(assuming a b c cocrete types) I will chose a to be a int and b to be an invoice and c lets say string, now I want represent a client for this command which should be a is an int b is a client and c is string should I create new command type for that and implement it separately ?

Comment: @CountOren, sorry, but I can't get you. please use proper formattin to ditinguish between English language and code.

Comment: To represent my domain: Will I have to define a new type for each of the objects for example 1) CRUDInvoice string thirdPartyInvoice ... 2) CRUDClient int thhirdPartyClient ...?

Comment: @CountOren, nope. `CRUD` is a single, generic interface to be reused across an entire application. you would implement different kinds of `Command` and feed it into appropriate `CRUD` instance.

Comment: So each `CRUD` instance should be built from algebraic types of different commands(read for invoice, read for client...) or should i have different instances `readInvoice`, `readClient` ?

Comment: `read` is generic function. you define it once for each and every possible `Command`. It will never ever be repeated. Commands are domain-specific: you got a `getInvoiceCommand`, `deleteUserCommand`, `updateOtherDomainObjectCommand` and you got a `crudBuilder` that is responsible for giving a rightly assembled `CRUD` instance to a right consumer.

Comment: so a b c... are generic types?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185633/discussion-between-sereja-bogolubov-and-countoren).